# GraphQL apollo client crashes with socket hang up

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am having an Graphql apollo-client and Apollo server (Node.js) both are working fine, but when the server takes more than 2 minitues to process the data my apollo-client crashes with

> "Network Error: request to http://localhost:8080/graphql failed,
> reason: socket hang up "

This is my apollo-client configuration

```
        const httpLink = () => (createHttpLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
        fetch: fetch as any
      }));

      const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
        if (graphQLErrors) {
          graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
            console.log(`GraphQL Error: ${message}`),
          );
        }
        if (networkError) {
          console.log(`Network Error: ${networkError.message}`);
        }
      });

      const timeoutLink = new ApolloLinkTimeout(600000);
    const links = ApolloLink.from([
        errorLink,
        httpLink(),
        timeoutLink as any
      ]);
    this.client = new ApolloClientBase({
        link: links,
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
```

I am trying to increase the timeout but I am not able to do it. I have tried the connect-timeout (express) in server side also but noting helped.

Comment: Any idea as to what caused this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, and when it happens it takes my entire nextjs instance with it.